# Sublime Text: Multiple Select in a Selection

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, multipleselection

I want to do multiple select and edit within a specified selection in Sublime Text 2. The following screenshot illustrates the situation:

[image]

When I select "element" and press Alt + F3 (in Windows) I can simultaneously edit all instances of element. However what I would like to do is to be able to edit all instances of element only within container-a while leaving element within container-b untouched. I tried first selecting a specific area but then as soon as I attempt to select "element" my first selection disappears.

Is this possible to achieve in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: this is a good question man, I'd like to know an answer for this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `Find in Selection` option in the `Find` panel. Select the text that you want to search in:

[image: selection]

then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open the `Find` panel. Type in the text you want to find (such as ***`element`***), then, in the group of buttons to the left of the text area, click the second button from the right - `In Selection` (highlighted in red):

[image: Find In Selection]

Finally, either hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or click `Find All` to select all the instances of `element` in the selected area:

[image: found]

and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+D to select one more element and then one more again until you have selected all elements in container-a.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - this is quite a handy shortcut. But is there a way to simultaneously select all of the elements within container-a? There could be quite a few instances of element and I am looking for a way to quickly select all instead of adding them one by one.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm looking forward for an answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry my approach is very similar, but just a tiny thing to make it very slightly faster.)

Before you start, have the setting "`auto_find_in_selection`" to true,  (This is probably only for SublimeText 3).  This will have the "In Selection" button automatically done in most cases.

1. (if you are already under the word) use **Ctrl+E** (command `slurp_find_string`).  This causes the word to be used in find box.
2. select the region you want (Ctrl+Shift+J should work nicely in your case)
3. Hit **Ctrl+F**, you will find all settings are right ("In Selection" on, your word in box already)
4. Just hit **Alt+Enter** and you are there.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, select what you want and then you can use --> cmd+ctrl+g